# How do you use fast-user switching on Windows 8.1 with an account that doesn't have a password?

Tags: windows-8.1

I have 2 accounts on a Windows 8.1 computer.  Normally to switch users I press Windows+L to go to the lock screen.  Then I click somewhere to bring up the login screen and press the back arrow to go to the screen showing my user accounts.  However, if my account does not have a password, the login screen is only shown briefly before I'm automatically logged in.  How do I switch from the non-password-protected account to another account without logging out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, my way of switching accounts was somewhat roundabout.  Instead, you should go to the Start screen (e.g., by pressing the Windows key), then click on your username in the top right corner.  From here you can select a different user account.

More info here:

Microsoft's [User Accounts: FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/user-accounts-faq#) also describes this process:

> If you have more than one account on your PC, you can switch to a
>   different account without signing out or closing apps. To switch to a
>   different account, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Open Start by swiping in from the right edge of the screen and then
>      tapping Start. (Or, if you're using a mouse, point to the lower-left
>      corner of the screen, move your mouse all the way into the corner, and
>      then click Start.)
> 2. Tap or click your account picture, and then choose another account
>      from the menu.

Comment: But how do you do it from the lock screen? -- The back button is missing.  It seems you can only login to the same account that locked it. :-/